# Redirect After Creating a Node - bootstrap.inc

Tags: bootstrapping

I wanted to create a node from a standalone php file bootstrapping drupal.
I printed out the form and it creates a node perfectly but it doesn't redirect to the created page or any other page for that-matter.

i would be grateful if someone points me to how to achieve that. I tried to use `hook_alter_form` but i can't get it to work

this is what i am using now

```
<?php

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/home/xxx/public_html/am');
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'xxx.com';

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

?>


<?php
$form = node_add('user_submited');
print drupal_render($form);

?>
```

ps. One of the reasons i wanted the form to load fast, currently in my theme  its about 200kb with 21 requests to load the form creation page, now its about 4kb with 3 requests .

Comment: A bit dangerous allowing anyone to post the form.

Comment: wow, i didn't know that @2pha . could you direct me to a better way ?

Comment: Do it with a drupal module implementing hook_menu instead of your own .php file